# Clarification of what/how to deploy the output of "grunt build"

Tags: apache, gruntjs

I have a simple web app. I am able to view the all using "`grunt serve`", and to build to a folder "`dist`" using "`grunt build`".  The `dist` folder has two folders: `public` and `server`.

I'd like to deploy this to the Apache HTTP server.  I am kinda stuck on what files to copy to the `htdocs` (`DocumentRoot`) in the web server.

I really appreciate any pointers on how to deploy the output of the `grunt build` to an Apache HTTP server.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I used grunt very little but from my experience you should put the files from either `server/dist` or `node_server/dist` (replace '/' with '\' if on windows), depending on the version of grunt you are using into your apache DocumentRoot
I may be wrong though and this might just be how our specific build is configured.